# Splitting text files and returning only the end in scala

Tags: scala

I want to read a text file from scala named "c.txt" that contains

```
CatManC_NAA
Foranz_CSW
Foresan_SQW
```

and return only the second part of the txt file as a string. Ex: NAA, CSW when entering "CatManC" or "Foranz" as a parameter while ignoring capitalization.
This is my code at the moment.

```
object Test {
  def getCode(fileName: String, nameInput:String): String={
  code:String=""
  for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines) {
    line.split("_")
   if (nameInput==line){
    line.takeRight(3)
     code+=line
}
   else{
   return ""
}
    
   
  }
code
}
```

I'm an amateur at coding and also new to the language. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to return something that can be used for multiple lookups or just a single look-up? if the latter, then you want to stop reading the file on the first match?

Comment: Just a single lookup. I just need to return the second part of the text that is separated by the "_" whenever it is inputted in the nameInput parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to write something like this:

```
  def getCode(fileName: String, nameInput: String): String = {
    import scala.util.control.Breaks
    var code = ""
    val source = Source.fromFile(fileName)
    val loopBreak = new Breaks
    loopBreak.breakable {
      for (line <- source.getLines()) {
        if (line.toLowerCase.contains(nameInput.toLowerCase)) {
          code = line.split("_")(1)
          loopBreak.break()
        }
      }
    }
    source.close()
    code
  }
```

Here *Breaks* needs to stop read file when we find what we are looking for. Method *toLowerCase* need to ignore capitalisation on both sides in file and in input.

Comment: Thank you for this! Is there also a way to return an empty string ("") if the nameInput is not found in the text file?

Comment: @JacksonC that is what the code already does.

Answer (score 1):

This would be the idiomatic, safe and efficient way of doing what you want.

```scala
import scala.io.Source
import scala.util.{Try, Using}

def getCode(fileName: String, nameInput: String): Try[Option[String]] = {
  val key = nameInput.toLowerCase

  Using(Source.fromFile(fileName)) { source =>
    source.getLines().map(_.split('_').map(_.toLowerCase).toList).collectFirst {
      case `key` :: value :: Nil => value
    }
  }
}
```

The `Try` is used to signal that processing the file may fail for multiple reasons; e.g. the file not existing.
The `Option` is used to signal that the `nameInput` key may not be present, thus there may not be output.

Ideally, you would handle both kinds of errors, probably by turning everything into an `Either[Error, String]` so you don't have to deal with nesting; like this:

```scala
import scala.io.Source
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try, Using}

sealed abstract class GetCodeError(cause: Option[Throwable]) extends Throwable(cause.orNull)
object GetCodeError {
  final case class FileError(cause) extend GetCodeError(cause = Some(cause))
  final case object KeyNotFoundError extends GetCodeError(cause = None)
}

def getCode(fileName: String, nameInput: String): Either[GetCodeError, String] = {
  val key = nameInput.toLowerCase

  val result = Using(Source.fromFile(fileName)) { source =>
    source.getLines().map(_.split('_').map(_.toLowerCase).toList).collectFirst {
      case `key` :: value :: Nil => value
    }
  }

  result match {
    case Sucess(opt) =>
      opt.toRight(left = GetCodeError.KeyNotFoundError)

    case Failure(ex) =>
      Left(GetCodeError.FileError(cause = ex))
  }
}
```

Or you may just forget about those errors and let the program crash if something wrong happens; like this:

```scala
import scala.io.Source
import scala.util.Using

def getCode(fileName: String, nameInput: String): String = {
  val key = nameInput.toLowerCase

  Using.resource(Source.fromFile(fileName)) { source =>
    source.getLines().map(_.split('_').map(_.toLowerCase).toList).collectFirst {
      case `key` :: value :: Nil => value
    }.get
  }
}
```

But please, don't do that on a real project. Although, this may be fine for a quick script.

---

If you have any questions about the code, please feel free to ask them!